# Empty graphobject on OG request

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-android-sdk

When trying to post an activity to Facebook from a native Android application, I get the following response after executing the request:

```
{
    Response: responseCode: 200,
    graphObject: null,
    error: {
        HttpStatus: -1,
        errorCode: -1,
        errorType: null,
        errorMessage: null
    },
    isFromCache: false
}
```

My app gets the publish_action permission from the user.

```
public void publishActivity(){
    session = Session.getActiveSession();
    openSession();

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("highest", "http://www.my-url.com/graph.html");

    Request request = new Request(
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            "me/namespace:play",
            params,
            HttpMethod.POST
        );
        Response response = request.executeAndWait();
    Log.d("DEBUG",response.toString());     
}

public void openSession(){
    if(session.isClosed()){
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(GameActivity.get());
        openRequest.setPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        session.openForPublish(openRequest);
    }
}
```

(I replaced the url and the namespace. In my code, they are correct.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be in the KeyHash provided by the namespace. It had changed, and it was not added in the Facebook Developers page yet.